# Installing multiple packages in parallel on linux

Tags: linux, package-management

Pardon boundaries of my knowledge, but I wonder why still only one instance of any package manger can be run on a system? Why multiple installations are not possible? If there's a way to achieve this it'll be really helpful..

Comment: Not in parallel, but you can install multiple packages with a single command `apt-get install package1 package2 package3 ... packageN`, similarly with `yum` or `pacman` or whichever package manager you use.

Comment: yeah i know, that just installs packages one after another..

Comment: On Gentoo Linux, it is possible to run different `emerge` commands in parallel.  Though I always wondered whether it is a good idea to do so...

Answer (score 4):

Mostly because it's possible for packages to make changes to shared system files, and currently there's no method for keeping track of which shared system files the packages' contents, pre-installation or removal scripts, or post-installation or removal scripts make changes to.

If two packages try to modify the same system file at the same time, there is a good chance that the file will be mangled and broken, leading to very bad behavior of the system. Updating the graphics driver and the X Server package at the same time may render the system unable to display a graphical login / interface for the user! This would be very bad.

In theory, you *could* keep track of this information, and run everything in parallel except for the packages that have to be run one-at-a-time, but this adds a considerable amount of complexity to the package management software and dependency resolution, and generally isn't worth it for the benefits. Usually, the bottleneck is somewhere else - downloading the packages, or the harddrive. If your harddrive is slow, installing packages in parallel can actually *slow down* package installation.